# QGIS: Unable to project raster layers correctly on a Toshiba Tecra 64# Win7

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I know how to project a raster, I can do it on other machines. On this particular machine the raster loads but are no where near the correct position as if the datum is on another planet.

Comment: Have you tried that exact same raster on another computer, and had it work?

Comment: i doubt that it has anything to do with your hardware and system. But what's your QGIS version?

Comment: I have tried the same rasters on a 32# XP machine and it works. I am running QGIS version 1.8.0-Lisboa. Could I be missing some kind of projection libary? I can see all the standard projections in the list and can warp my rasters but they are still in the wrong place.